# JS: get runtime 'this' from outside function

Tags: javascript

`this` inside a function is set on runtime:

```
var person = {  
  hello: function(thing) {
    console.log(this, " says hello " + thing);
  }
}

// the code:
person.hello("world");

// is equivalent to:
person.hello.call(person, "world");
```

Is it possible, starting from a reference to a binded function (to an object), to get that object? Something like:

```
var misteryFunction = person.hello;
misteryFunction.getMyRuntimeThis() // returns: person
```

Comment: `this` is dynamically bound to the object the method is called on. That means as long as your `misteryFunction` isn't invoked via `apply`, `call` or bound with `bind` you can't determine it's receiver.

Answer (score 2):

Not out of the box (javascript is not python). One way is to create a copy of the object with all methods bound to it:

```js
var boundObject = function(obj) {
  var res = {};
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(k) {
    var x = obj[k];
    if(x.bind)
      x = x.bind(obj);
    res[k] = x;
  });
  return res;
}

//

var person = {  
  name: 'Joe',
  hello: function(thing) {
    console.log(this.name + " says hello " + thing);
  }
}

helloJoe = boundObject(person).hello;
helloJoe('there')
```

Can be also done more efficiently with proxies.